# nvd3 passing wrong event on stateChange (when clicking legend) after chart is reloaded

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, nvd3.js

I have a nvd3 multibar chart (but the same problem occurs with a pie chart).

I want to save the status of the legend when the user enables or disables a series, by clicking on it in the legend. So I'm listening to *stateChange* events.

In the following example code there are two series. When the user clicks, say, on *series1* to disable it, the console should log:

```
New State: {"disabled":[true,false]}
```

The problem starts occurring after refreshing the chart with new data from the server (simulated by *setInterval* in the code below). After the first refresh I always get a wrong event, i.e., **values of the *disabled* attribute are messed up**.

Maybe the way I refresh the graph is wrong?

Here the sample code:

```
  var initialData = [
      { key: 'series1', values: [
            { x: 0, y: 10},
            { x: 1, y: 44}
          ]},
      { key: 'series2', values: [
            { x: 0, y: 25},
            { x: 1, y: 11}
          ]}
    ];

  var chart;
  nv.addGraph(function() {

      chart = nv.models.multiBarChart()
        .delay(0);

      d3.select('#chart1 svg')
          .datum(initialData)
          .call(chart);

      nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

      chart.dispatch.on('stateChange', function(e) {
        nv.log('New State:', JSON.stringify(e));
      });


      setInterval(function ()
      {
        var newDataFromServer = [
          { key: 'series1', values: [
                { x: 0, y: Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1)},
                { x: 1, y: Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1)}
              ]},
          { key: 'series2', values: [
                { x: 0, y: Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1)},
                { x: 1, y: Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1)}
              ]}
        ];

        d3.select('#chart1 svg')
          .datum(newDataFromServer)
          .call(chart);

        nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

      }, 5000);

      return chart;
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found a working solution. I don't have time to investigate further, but in the following code (*nvd3/legend.js*):

```
  .on('click', function(d,i) {
    dispatch.legendClick(d,i);
    if (updateState) {
       if (radioButtonMode) {
            // etc ...
       }
       else {
            // Note: this 'd' doesn't belong to the 'data' array in the current scope
           d.disabled = !d.disabled;
           // etc ...
       }
       dispatch.stateChange({
          // The old data is notified as event
          disabled: data.map(function(d) { return !!d.disabled })
       });
    }
  })
```

when it is misbehaving (i.e., after the first update), the **d object doesn't belong to the *data* array** in this scope (it is supposed to do). I guess this *data* always points to the initial data array.

As a workaround to update the chart, I get the initial array and update it in-place:

```
// Get reference to data array object
var chartDatum = d3.select('#chart1 svg')
                        .datum();
// Clear array and copy new data into it                        
chartDatum.length = 0;
angular.extend(chartDatum, newDataFromServer); // Or jQuery extend, or equivalent
chart.update();
```

Comment: I wonder if you the issue might be related to the two datasets have the same keys.